# How to solve Error: unexpected '$' in "$" in R?

Tags: r, list

I am new to R and am trying to solve a simple problem. I get the error:
*Error: unexpected '$' in "$"*
while running the following code in RStudio

```
list('x' = 1, 'y' = 2, 'z' = 3)

$`x`
```

I have also tried $x, but I still get the same error.

Can someone please help me? Thank You!

Comment: The problem is that the instruction giving error is not valid R code. `$` extracts from an object, not from nothing (there's nothing preceding it). To extract from the list you must do `list('x' = 1, 'y' = 2, 'z' = 3)$x` or assign the list to an object first, then extract the member `x`. Run `lst <- list('x' = 1, 'y' = 2, 'z' = 3)` followed by `lst$x`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas, Thank you very much. This helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you intended your code

```
list('x' = 1, 'y' = 2, 'z' = 3)
$`x`
```

to be a single statement, but that's not how R parses it.  It sees two statements, because the first line is a complete statement.  But the second line is not a valid statement, so you get the error.

You can get it to work by putting everything on one line:

```
list('x' = 1, 'y' = 2, 'z' = 3)$`x`
```

or by making sure the first line is incomplete:

```
list('x' = 1, 'y' = 2, 
     'z' = 3)$`x`
```